# How to execute a function after a trigger

Tags: python

I want to build a function that is executed after x games (runs).

I therefore set `if run % 5 == 0:`, but I noticed, that the function is executed not once but many times (which was not my intend).

Here`s the code:

```
def update_weights(self, run):
        if run % UPDATE_MODEL == 0:
            weights = self.model.get_weights()
            self.target_model.set_weights(weights)
            print("Updated Model")

while True:
        run += 1
        while True:
                step += 1
                more code...
                if done:
                        break
                update_weights()
```

When I run this code it prints:

```
Updated Model
Updated Model
Updated Model
...
```

(thats why I noticed this in the first place)

Comment: You never pass `update_weights` an argument, and `step` & `run` are undefined. The code you have here should have errored out in several ways. That being said are you sure it is updating every round? Add a print outside of the `if` in `update_weights` to double check.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Just had to say... I thought up your name was part of your comment as a link. As it fit so well into the comment

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: if it was `def update_weights():` this would work, provided the function is called in the right scope (within which `self` and `run` are defined). Anyway, I'd say the question needs clarification so that it becomes clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: @MrFuppes I agree on both statements. This code should work but there is a lot of missing context so the OP needs to add his actual code not have baked pseudo code.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse / addition: I agree with you that declaring function parameters explicitly is better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `update_weights` is called only once per run, here it's being indefinitely called in the second nested while loop.

I believe it should be in the first while loop.